# Defining a counter

Tags: numbering, counters

I'm trying to define a new counter which does the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document} 
\begin{longtable}{lll} 
\circled{x} \quad  $3x^4-x^4-x^3(x+2)$ & 
\circled{x} \quad  $-12a^2+3a(a+1)$ &
\circled{x} \quad  $ax^n+4x^n$ 
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

In the circles there should be 1., 2. and so on.

Is it possible to define a counter which counts automaticly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following works:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcounter{circled}
\newcommand*\circled{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
  \stepcounter{circled}
  \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {\arabic{circled}};}}

\begin{document} 
\begin{longtable}{lll} 
  \circled \quad  $3x^4-x^4-x^3(x+2)$ & 
  \circled \quad  $-12a^2+3a(a+1)$ &
  \circled \quad  $ax^n+4x^n$ 
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

A new counter, `circled`, is declared with `\newcounter`. It gets incremented by `\stepcounter` (which increments it automatically by 1; if you want other increments, use `\addtocounter`). Finally, its numerical value is printed with `\arabic` (you could use `\roman` or `\Roman` for Roman numerals instead).

Finally, note that the code you provided isn't minimal (as in [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). It doesn't really matter here, but in general providing a minimal code will help you spot errors and make it easier for people here to help you :)

Comment: The macro `\thecircled` which is defined with `\newcounter` gives a consistent way to use the counter and can be redefined to `\roman` or `\Roman` (`\renewcommand*{\thecircled}{\Roman{circled}}`).